# Setting ScrollPane to the Desired Position

Tags: java, javafx

I am developing a project in JavaFX 2.0.

The scenario starts when a user creates a UML model like below:

[image]

When the user clicks the source code synchronisation button, the application displays the related source codes in Bubbles around the UML model like following:

[image]

However, as you might realize that the bubble, which is created on the top is not fully fit the pane. The desired view of the pane should be like this:

[image]

Even if I know that I should use `HValue` and `VValue` properties to accomplish this. I couldn't understand how should I set these new value of `ScrollPane`.

The size of the ScrollPane is 8000 x 8000 and I am creating an invisible rectangle which covers all the UML model and the bubbles by calling rescaleView() function. So according to the values of this rectangle, I am rescaling the ScrollPane but I couldn't move the viewport centre again. Here is the function for rescaling:

```
private void rescaleView() {
    double MARGIN = 5.0;

    List<BubbleView> bubbleViews = new ArrayList<>(diagramController.getAllBubbleViews());

    double xMin = bubbleViews.get(0).getX();
    double yMin = bubbleViews.get(0).getY();
    double xMax = bubbleViews.get(0).getX() + bubbleViews.get(0).getWidth();
    double yMax = bubbleViews.get(0).getY() + bubbleViews.get(0).getHeight();

    if(bubbleViews.size() > 0) {
        for(int i = 1; i < bubbleViews.size(); i++) {
            if((bubbleViews.get(i).getX() + bubbleViews.get(i).getWidth()) > xMax) {
                xMax = bubbleViews.get(i).getX() + bubbleViews.get(i).getWidth();
            }

            if(bubbleViews.get(i).getX() < xMin) {
                xMin = bubbleViews.get(i).getX();
            }

            if((bubbleViews.get(i).getY() + bubbleViews.get(i).getHeight()) > yMax) {
                yMax = bubbleViews.get(i).getY() + bubbleViews.get(i).getHeight();
            }

            if(bubbleViews.get(i).getY() < yMin) {
                yMin = bubbleViews.get(i).getY();
            }
        }

        double toBeScaled = Math.min((Math.max(diagramController.getScrollPane().getWidth(), diagramController.getScrollPane().getHeight()) / Math.max((xMax - xMin), (yMax - yMin))),(Math.min(diagramController.getScrollPane().getWidth(), diagramController.getScrollPane().getHeight()) / Math.min((xMax - xMin), (yMax - yMin)))) * 100;
        diagramController.getGraphController().zoomPane(toBeScaled - MARGIN);
        diagramController.getGraphController().center(xMin, yMin);
    }
}
```

but the `center(x,y)` function below doesn't make the viewport center:

```
public void center(double x, double y) {
    ScrollPane scrollPane = diagramController.getScrollPane();

    double xScroll = x / 8000; //8000 is the size of aDrawPane set in view.classDiagramView.fxml
    double yScroll = y / 8000;

    scrollPane.setHvalue(xScroll);
    scrollPane.setVvalue(yScroll);
}
```

How should I set these `setHValue` and `setVValue`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it works or not.

```
diagramController.getGraphController().center((xMax + xMin) / 2, (yMax + yMin) / 2);
```

---

```
double xScroll = (x - scrollPane.getWidth() / 2) / (8000 - scrollPane.getWidth());
double yScroll = (y - scrollPane.getHeight() / 2) / (8000 - scrollPane.getHeight());
```

And `toBeScaled` seems to have undesirable case such as vertically long scrollPane with wide contents. Ignore the code below if it was misunderstanding.

```
final double scrollPaneWidth = diagramController.getScrollPane().getWidth();
final double scrollPaneHeight = diagramController.getScrollPane().getHeight();
final double contentsWidth = xMax - xMin;
final double contentsHeight = yMax - yMin;
double toBeScaled = Math.min(scrollPaneHeight / contentsHeight, scrollPaneWidth / contentsWidth) * 100;
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot! By the way, you were right about the mistake in toBeScaled. I have changed it as you said.